# CakePHP loadModel not working

Tags: cakephp

I have created a Model named "Usermgmt" and I am using table for this model is "users" in following manner.

```
public $useTable = "users";
```

Now I am loading this Model into different controller named "MembersController" in following manner

```
public $this->loadModel('Usermgmt');
```

But it is showing error when I load this model into "MembersController" controller- table "usermgmts" missing for "Usermgmt" model.

And it is working fine in "UsermgmtController" without showing table "usermgmts" missing error and saving data correctly into the "Users" table.

NOTE- I do not have any table with named - "usermgmts" as I am using "users" table for "Usermgmt" Model

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `public` portion and call it from inside a function:

So if you are trying to add this is a function in `MembersController`, you would the add it like this:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class MembersController extends AppController {

  public function myFunction() { 
    $this->loadModel('Usermgmt');
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code from your Controller function where you are trying to use this?